# Visual Basic - Is operator

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class EquipmentNode
 '...
End Class

Private Sub DoWork()
 Dim node As TreeNode = _contextNode

 If node is EquipmentNode ' Does not work
 if node is TypeOf EquipmentNode ' Does not work
End Sub
```

How can I see if the node is the same type.  Right now I'm just casting it and seeing if the result is null, but I want to make use of the "Is" operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Visual Basic Is Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx), (unlike the [C#'s is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)), does not tell you about the object's *type*, but rather whether two objects variables refer to the same actual object instance.

> The Is operator determines if two object references refer to the same object

This will not tell you whether the object is a specific type.

To compare types, you'd use:

```
If TypeOf node Is EquipmentNode Then
```

Comment: Ah, okay.  I was thinking it was the same as c#

Answer (score 2):

The [`Is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) in VB doesn't - as `is` in C# - check if an object is of a certain type, it does the same job as C#'s [`ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Comment: It's not really C#'s ReferenceEquals, it's the .NET ReferenceEquals.